# sys.setrecursionlimit() and recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, sys

I don't understand why the code is running 170 times instead of using the `sys` function by setting its limit to 200.

```
import sys
i=0
def fun1():
    global i
    print("hello i = ",i)
    i+=1
    fun1()
print("Welcome")
sys.setrecursionlimit(200)
fun1()
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

Why is my code running 170 times only instead it should run 200 times.
Also can you please explain me how the `fun1` inside `fun1` is giving me error?

I don't know some people are telling that in some other editor other than jupiter it is giving the correct result.
but as I am using Jupyter it is giving the wrong result as 170 times.

Comment: 170 seems a liitle bit low but you'll never reach 200. `setrecursionlimit` sets the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack and not the limit for just one specific recursion. It seems as if Jupyter does some calls itself before it executes your code.

Comment: Exactly: Jupyter is written in Python, and evidently there's about 30 stack frames before your code is run. (See what a bare `traceback.print_stack()` gives you.)

Comment: On my laptop it's 168, and 968 when depth is increased to 1000. Also confirming your explanations, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python max recursion, question about sys.setrecursionlimit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081448/python-max-recursion-question-about-sys-setrecursionlimit)

Comment: If you're thinking about messing with `setrecursionlimit()`, best to use iteration rather than trying to kick the can further. Treat the recursion limit as the untouchable implementation detail it is.