# Why is my recursion limit not being respected?

Tags: python, recursion

Consider this example:

```py
import math
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(100)

max_items = 10


def foo(ls):
    if -(len(ls) // -max_items) >= sys.getrecursionlimit():
        raise ValueError("List is too long. You'll hit the recusion limit")
    ls, ls_ = ls[:max_items], ls[max_items:]
    print(len(ls_))
    if len(ls_) > 0:
        foo(ls_)


foo(list(range(970)))
```

I would expect that my logic for raising a `ValueError` before the recursion limit is reached is correct. That is, I'm calculating the total number of times `foo` would need to be called (including the initial call) to process the list, and checking if that is equal to or above the recursion limit.

But for some reason even calling `foo(list(range(970)))` raises `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. Maybe I'm not understanding what the argument of `setrecursionlimit` is?

**EDIT**: I had the recursion limit as 5 before but that's not working on many people's machines so I changed it to be much higher to avoid confusion about what the source of the error is.

Comment: Hi. Are you sure you mean *"calling `foo(9)`"*? From the code, the argument of `foo` is expected to be something that has a `len`. The integer `9` does not have a `len`.

Comment: @Stef thanks. No I didn't mean that. Corrected.

Comment: The so-called "recursion limit" is actually the limit for the entire call stack. Depending on how you run your code, a limit of 5 can be reached even before your function starts.

Comment: Also, in general instead of using floating-point division `a / b` and then wrapping it inside a math.ceil` or `math.floor`, it's better and simpler to use integer division directly: `a // b`

Comment: @Stef typically I would try to make the code more readable by favoring `math.ceil(a / b)` over `-(- a // b)`. But I think you're saying that I could get a numerical error? (I know it's appropriate to take this conversation aside but SO doesn't really give an easy way to do that)

Comment: When I run your code, I get `RecursionError: cannot set the recursion limit to 5 at the recursion depth 8: the limit is too low`. The error comes from `setrecursionlimit` call, not from `foo`

Comment: @Lesiak I can confirm that's definitely not what I get. Perhaps it's a system / environment thing. The example still stands if you set a higher number. I had it low to look at some printout.

Comment: @Matthias I guess I have some learning to do. Do you have a tldr of how I would manage this then? I mean I want to get an idea of how many recursive calls `foo` will need given my actual use case. Recursion turns out to be an elegant solution to a problem we have, but I'll avoid it if it's likely to reach the limit.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Personally I don't find a long verbose operation using `math.ceil` "more readable" than arithmetic using symbols, but that's debatable of course. Here is a related question: [Is there a ceiling equivalent of // operator in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822184/is-there-a-ceiling-equivalent-of-operator-in-python)

Comment: With the new edit, I don't understand your interrogation. You have a list of length 970, and you divide by 10 to get the number of recursive calls, so you're left with 97 calls. Then you compare this to 100. Of course 97 < 100, so you don't hit your custom `ValueError`. So what is it that you find surprising?

Comment: @Stef the surprise is that I hit the `RecursionError`. I believed that my logic for the `ValueError` would cover me but it didn't. This reveals that I don't know how to calculate in advance that I'd get a `RecursionError`, which implies I don't understand how the recursion limit works.

Comment: Oh! Well this is best explained by @Matthias 's comment above. Despite its name, the so-called "recursion limit" is not a limit on the number of recursive calls, but on the number of function calls. This includes your 97 recursive calls, plus the `print` or `len` calls inside your deepest recursive call, plus whatever other calls are on top of that. There might even be a small number of "invisible" calls made by the interpreter on top of the calls you made explicitly in your code.

Comment: @Stef yep. And Goku's link says that more or less. I've flagged my question as a duplicate. Not sure how many more votes it will take before it takes effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite its name, the so-called "recursion limit" is not a limit on the number of recursive calls, but on the number of function calls.

This includes:

- your 97 recursive calls;
- plus the `print` or `len` calls inside your deepest recursive call;
- plus whatever calls you made before your first recursive call, for instance to a `main` function;
- plus possibly a small number of "invisible" calls made by the interpreter on top of the calls you made explicitly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Document says,

https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit

*If the new limit is too low at the current recursion depth, a RecursionError exception is raised.
Changed in version 3.5.1: A RecursionError exception is now raised if the new limit is too low at the current recursion depth.*

I am getting RecursionError for anything below 40

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(39)

RecursionError: cannot set the recursion limit to 39 at the recursion depth 28: the limit is too low
```

---

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(40)

# No error
```

Edit

check this link : [Python max recursion, question about sys.setrecursionlimit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081448/python-max-recursion-question-about-sys-setrecursionlimit)

Comment: To be clear. I don't get this error. I'll edit my example to rule it out for everyone else hopefully.

Comment: In the beginning you posted `sys.setrecursionlimit(5)`  we all were getting `RecursionError` for that value.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare check if this answer is helpful in any way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081448/python-max-recursion-question-about-sys-setrecursionlimit

Comment: That's good. I'd be even willing to mark my q as a duplicate

Comment: Glad you got your answer:)

Answer (score -1):

You did set the limit 100 and for `list(range(970))` recursion depth will be 97 which is less than 100. Run it for `foo(list(range(1000)))` and it will throw an exception.

```
try:
    foo(list(range(1000)))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

output will be :

```
List is too long. You'll hit the recusion limit
```

Comment: That's true. My point though, is that running it for 97 raises a RecursionError, which means that clearly my understanding of how to calculate that in advance is incorrect.

Comment: its running without any error for 970. it might be because of low memory issue on your machine.

Comment: I don't think that's right. I think my answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081448/python-max-recursion-question-about-sys-setrecursionlimit